# Google Custom Search engine popular searches widget

Tags: google-custom-search

I remember years ago there used to be a widget you could use from the Google Custom Search engine that allowed you to embed details of popular searches on your public web pages. I have been looking for the documentation again for that recently so I can implemement it on a site that has a Custom Search Engine but now cannot find it - even with Google! Is this functionality still available or is it something that should be done with Google Analytics.

For an answer I am looking for links to official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Custom Search help page that discusses this. [Custom Search Help: Stats](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2717683)

> The Stats tab of the Statistics and Logs page shows you popular
>   queries for your Custom Search Engine. You can view this info by day,
>   week, month, or year—even the entire lifetime of your search engine.
>   The Stats page provides accurate data about the search usage and the
>   total number of searches completed.
>
> To display popular queries on your site (for example, to help
>   searchers find popular pages), copy the code in the Popular web
>   queries page and paste it into your pages.

Comment: Thanks! The publicly available data is strictly limited - that's a shame!